# Show the data with mysql_query php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables on database, table 'songs', and 'genre'.

- Table 'songs' has 3 columns: id_song (PK), song_title, lyric, id_genre
- Table 'genre' has 2 columns: id_genre (PK), genre

in table 'genre', i have:

> || id_genre | genre ||
>
> ||.......1.......|..pop...||
>
> ||.......2.......|..rock..||
>
> ||.......3.......|..jazz...||
>
> ||.......4.......|.classic.||

Relation between 2 tables:

> song.id_genre FK to genre.id_genre

I have a variable like this:

```
$search_genre = 'pop';
```

and I want to search song by `$search_genre`.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT song.id_song, song.song_title, genre.genre FROM song WHERE genre='$search_genre' INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre ORDER BY id_song");
```

But, it doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks for your help.

Question 2: How to show the result in php?

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: For the second question, seriously rtfm.

Answer (score 7):

## First!

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

## Second!

If you've already started with `mysql_*` at the very least escape your parameters! Otherwise you're leaving a gaping SQL injection security vulnerability waiting for the next l33t wannabe hacker to hack into your site!

```
$search_genere = mysql_real_escape_string($search_genere);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT song.id_song, song.song_title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre.genre='".$search_genre."' ORDER BY id_song");
```

But please *please* do read the link in the box above.

The reason you've had this error is because of a syntax error.

Comment: can you help me, how to show the result in php? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Your `JOIN` query is wrong you use `INNER JOIN` after `FROM`

Try this:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT song.id_song, song.song_title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre='%$search_genre%'  ORDER BY id_song");
```

If you querying a search you can use `wildcards` such as `%`

e.g.

```
query = mysql_query("SELECT song.id_song, song.song_title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre='%$search_genre%'  ORDER BY id_song");
```

Comment: You can check [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537583/show-the-data-with-mysql-query-php#comment23751924_16537724) for a reason why.

Answer (score -3):

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT song.id_song, song.song_title, genre.genre FROM song INNER JOIN genre ON song.id_genre=genre.id_genre WHERE genre.genre='".$search_genre."' ORDER BY id_song");

    use this.it will work.

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     echo $row['id_song'];//song id
     echo $row['song_title'];//song title
     echo $row['genre'];//song genre
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, i forget to ask 2nd question, how to show the result in php? Thanks for your help.